# Measure theory equality

Tags: measure-theory

I have the following equality in my notes but I don't understand why should it be true.
$||f||_p=sup_{g\in L^q,||g||_q=1}\int f(x)g(x)dx$

I just understand the $\geq$ by an Hölder argument but not the opposite equality... does someone see if this holds?

Comment: True for $1 \leq p < \infty$ (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#Dual_spaces).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you suppose $f$ non negative, you have the equality case for

$$
g = \frac{1}{C}f^{\frac1{q-1}}
$$
The $C$ constant is here to make $\|g\|_q = 1$. You can show that $g$ belongs to $L^q$ and that the equality case holds, i.e. $\int fg = \|f\|_p$.

If $f$ is not nonnegative, then you can take
$$
g = |f|^{\frac1{q-1}} \cdot \sigma
$$
with $\sigma$ taking values -1 or 1 and such that $f\sigma  = |f|$.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand it.. :/ why do you choose such a g?

Comment: As you said, you have $\|f\|_p > \int fg$ for all g by Holder inequality. But there is a $g$ that provides you the equality case. (I also edited my answer to make it true...)